# Python Selenium - AttributeError al usar is_displayed en find_element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, unittest

Escribo para solicitar su colaboración, ya soy nuevo en programación.
Estoy haciendo un pequeño test (pytest) a una pagina web.
Usando el elemento find_element(By.XPATH,"XPath"), quiero que devuelva True si encuentra el elemento, pero tambien False si no lo encuentra.

Para este ultimo solo me devuelve el error AttributeError, pero no es lo que necesito, es requerido devuelva False.

Les resumen del codigo del test.

Agradecido de la ayuda que me puedan prestar.

```py
class Test_Laboratorio():
    variable = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'xpath_elemento_no_existente').is_displayed()
    def test_laboratorio(self):
        assert self.variable == True
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el código HTML? Es muy complicado resolver tu duda con tan poca información

Comment: De manera vaga te puedo decir que puedes crear una condicional en caso de que exista dicho elemento: `if(len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//td[text()='xpath_elemento_no_existente']/following-sibling::td/input"))) > 0:`

Comment: @UlisesAntonioChávez
Este es parte del codigo html que testeo. Especificamente el elemento que se requiere testear.
Lo que quiero es testear el elemento "a" con class="link__Rz_ju"
Si este lo encuentra devuelve un True (OK), pero si no, devuelva un False.
Pero esto ultimo no ocurre, si no, un AttributeError

`<div class="toolbar__1BDpE">
<p class="text__20Fgv">
<a class="link__Rz_ju" title="Iniciar sesión">Iniciar sesión</a>
</p>
</div>`

Comment: Ok ya vi que tienes un `class`, necesito una captura de pantalla o el link del sitio. Lo que se tiene que realizar es un `driver.find_element_by_class_name("link__Rz_ju")`, pero no estoy seguro de que funcione

Answer (score 0):

Encontré una manera de solventar la duda que tenia.
Es forzar un booleano de la variable, y utilizar el "find_elements" para devolver una lista del xpath encontrado. Pero para evitar que liste elementos no deseados, se debe ser muy especifico con el XPATH html(Que sea irrepetible).

```
class Test_Laboratorio():
    variable = bool(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'xpath_elemento_no_existente')) #En este ejemplo devuelve False.
    def test_laboratorio(self):
        assert self.variable == True
```

Comment: Si ya has respondido tu pregunta, elígela como respuesta, aunque sea tuya